# How to remove mold from suit?

Tags: cleaning, laundry

While travelling to a very rainy place in India my luggage had to travel on the roof of the car. Although there was some cover the luggage still got quite wet and before I could do anything about it (we spent there several days) my suit(the trousers part) got mold. I would like to somehow clean it, but dry cleaners would not accept it. It seems the chemicals they use do not help against mold.

What options do I have? Any advices on how to clean mold from clothes?

Answer (score 1):

An ion generator can kill mould. I don't know if you can get them in India, but Japanese manufacturers Sharp and Panasonic make good ones. I use them when travelling.

Comment: Actually I was travelling to India, not living there :) Can you provide a link to ion generator? A couple of different things appear when I try to google for it.

Comment: Try searching for "Plasmacluster" and "Panasonic Nanoe".

Comment: First Google search result says this is not true: "The ionizer does nothing to kill or destroy the mold spores, it just makes them settle out of the air faster." https://molekule.com/blogs/all/can-an-ionizer-air-purifier-actually-kill-mold

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [Shout (Stain Remover)](http://www.shoutitout.com/en-US/Products/Pages/shout-refills.aspx) near you? I use it on all stains and it cleans very well, especially on clothes. However, I don't know the material of your suit so it may not work.